# Salesforce Customer Community and EC (error code) 301 Redirect

Tags: community, redirect, logout

We are working on a Napili Customer Community.

Sometimes I find that the site is redirecting to a ec-301 page:

[image]

It seems to occur if I shut my laptop with the site open, and then come back the next day and the page is then on www.salesforce.com.

We are trying to avoid any redirect to non-branded pages. A normal timeout seems to work correctly to take me back to the login page.

I seem to have found the Site URL Redirect page associated with my community, where I may be able to set this redirect.

[image]

Two questions:

1) What is this ec-301?

I found the following, but Im not able to relate it to why my Community User is getting the error (if the follow definition is relative to my issue)

**Status 301** means that the resource (page) is moved permanently to a new location. The client/browser should not attempt to request the original location but use the new location from now on.

**Status 302** means that the resource is temporarily located somewhere else, and the client/browser should continue requesting the original url.

2)  Is the Sire URL Redirect the correct place to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

To answer question number 2, for lightning communities (Napili Template), access Administration under Workspaces, and you can access sitestudio by going to Pages > Sitestudio.com:

[image]
and then Site Configuration > URL Redirects:
[image]

and create your rule.

Comment: Thanks. I had checked the Force.com site, but not the Site.com.

For someone who is new to Communities and only used to Community Builder, the Site.com and Force.com are very jarring.  For me, its not immediately obvious when and why to use either one.

Comment: =P you are welcome. make sure you upvote/check for answered (partial answer in this case) if all is good. thanks!